# cPickle saved object loaded modified - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

In my script, I'm trying to save a dictionary using **cPickle**. Everything works fine except the thing that loaded dictionary has **modified** each key.
My dictionary looks like: `{'a':[45,155856,26,98536], 'b':[88,68,9454,78,4125,52]...}`

When I print keys from this dictionary before saving it, it prints correct values: `'a','b'...`

But when I save it and then load using **cPickle**, each key contains `'\r'` after correct char: `'a\r','b\r'...`

Here is the code for saving:

```
def saveSuffixArrayDictA():
        for i in self.creation.dictA.keys():
            print len(i)
        print 'STOP'
        with open('dictA','w+') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.creation.dictA,f)
```

Which prints: `1,1,1,1,1,1....STOP` (with newlines of course)

Then, when I'm trying to load it using this:

```
@staticmethod
def dictA():
    with open('ddictA','rb') as f:
        dict = pickle.load(f)
    for i in dict.keys():
        print len(i)
    print 'STOP'
    return dict
```

It returns: `2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2...STOP` (with newlines of course)

As you can see it should be the same but it isn't... where could be the problem please?

EDIT: I tried to print values and realized that each item in list (list is value) has added 'L' at the end of this item which is a number.

Comment: What happens if you change the write mode from `w+` to `wb+`? (Since `w+` is a text mode, on Windows it will map `\n` to `\r\n`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#usage):

> Be sure to always open pickle files created with protocols >= 1 in binary
>   mode. For the old ASCII-based pickle protocol 0 you can use either text mode
>   or binary mode **as long as you stay consistent**. (my emphasis)

Therefore, do not write the pickle file in the text-mode `w+`, but read it in the binary mode `rb`.
Instead, use binary modes,  `wb+` and `rb`, for both.

---

[When you write in text mode](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/file-modes-in-python-text-binary-and.html) (e.g. `w+`), `\n` is mapped to the OS-specific end-of-line character(s). On Windows, `\n` is mapped to `\r\n`. That appears to be the source of the errant `\r`s appearing in the keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strange error and I don't know its reason. But here is another way for saving and loading data structures in python. Just convert your data structure to string using `str()` and write it to any `file`. Load the `file` back, read it in any variable and convert it back to data structure using `ast`. Demo is given below:

```
>>> import ast
>>> d={'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8],'c':[9,10]}
>>> saveDic=str(d)
>>> saveDic
"{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [9, 10], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]}"
# save this string to any file, load it back and convert to dictionary using ast
>>> d=ast.literal_eval(saveDic)
>>> d
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [9, 10], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]}
```